# jQuery textfield with predefined choices

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a form in which I want to have textfields, so when I click on it, much like a date picker, predefined values popup from which i can choose.

I have been scouting the net, but with no luck:-(

I have come across bootstraps [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo.html), but as I see this can not be used on formfields, and I want it to be a part of a form in wich I can submit the values.

If anyone can guide me in the right direction I would really apreciate it :-)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wont a dropdown element suffice for that?

Comment: Or, perhaps, a [`datalist`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist): [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4WFDw/)?

Comment: datalist is just perfect, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about autocomplete textfield.
E.g. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: OP's talking abt just two or three values popping up all the time, _even before typing anything_. Not from a searchable list (**i think**)

Comment: Not sure, he doesn't mention how many and the autocopmlete can also be activated when focussing (_when I click on it_) the textfield.

Comment: I am talking about, lets say I want to insert schoolgrades, and I want the garde options to popup.